# Как отобразить во вьюхе 2 контроллера

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

В форме создания профайла были поля юзера (почта, имя), чтобы можно было отправить подтверждение на почту:

```
= form_for @profile, html: { multipart: true } do |f|

  .field
    = f.label :Photo
    = f.file_field :photo
  .field
    = f.label :Cv
    = f.file_field :cv
  .field
    = f.label :fio
    = f.text_field :fio
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  .field
    = f.label :money_from
    = f.text_field :money_from
  .field
    = f.label :money_to
    = f.text_field :money_to
  .field
    = f.label :location
    = f.text_field :location
  .field
    = f.label :category
    = f.text_field :category
  .field
    = f.label :expectations
    = f.text_field :expectations
  .field
    = f.label :skype
    = f.text_field :skype
  .field
    = f.label :site
    = f.text_field :site
  .field
    = f.label :linkedin
    = f.text_field :linkedin

 = f.fields_for :users do |users_form|
   if user_singed_in? 
   .field
   = f.label :current_user.email
   else
    .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  .field
    = f.label :email
    = f.text_field :email
    end

end
  .actions = f.submit
end
```

Ошибка при создании профайла:

```
`Slim::Parser::SyntaxError at /profiles/new
Unknown line indicator
  /home/igorrize/juniorjobs/app/views/profiles/_form.html.slim, Line 43, Column 0
     fields_for :users do |users_form|
    ^
```

И еще выделяет 2-ю строку в `views/profile/new.html.slim`:

```
h1 New profile
== render 'form'
= link_to 'Back', profiles_path
```

Comment: `end`? В Slim-то? А вторая форма почему с отступом в один пробел? Конечно, Rails ничего не может сделать с синтаксически неправильным кодом :)

Comment: cапсибо это возможно рубокоп так сделал, в другой вьюхе `end` нету.
вообщем сделал вот так  `= f.fields_for :user do |builder|
    = builder.label :name
    = builder.text_field :name
    = builder.label :email
    = builder.text_field :email`
заработало